# Qprinter Extra margin at left Side

Tags: python-3.x, printing, pyqt5, qtextdocument, qprinter

I am using pyqt5
I used **QTextDocument** and tried to print a Text but i am Getting margin on left side.
I tried everything to remove the margin but it is still not going away.
I used **setPageMargins** and **setDocumentMargin** but still getting that margin on left side.

Here is the Code:

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QTextEdit, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QTextDocument, QTextCursor, QTextCharFormat,QTextFrameFormat,QTextBlockFormat
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import QPrinter, QPrintDialog,QPrintPreviewDialog
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtWidgets,QtGui
import sys

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('QTextDocument Example')

        central_widget = QWidget()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.text_edit = QTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.text_edit)

        self.generate_button = QPushButton('Generate Document')
        self.generate_button.clicked.connect(self.generateDocument)
        layout.addWidget(self.generate_button)

        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    def generateDocument(self):
        # Clear any previous content
        self.text_edit.clear()

        # Create a QTextDocument instance
        doc = QTextDocument()
        cursor = QTextCursor(doc)
        content = "HI there"
        cursor.insertText(content)
        printer = QPrinter()
        printer.setFullPage(True)
        printer.setPageMargins(0.1,0.1,0.1,0.1,QPrinter.Millimeter)
        printer.setPaperSize(QPrinter.PageSize.Letter)
        printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Orientation.Portrait)
        doc.setDocumentMargin(0)
        self.text_edit.setDocument(doc)
        doc.print_(printer)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the picture of one of the outputs The Content have a lot of **margin** on the **left side**.

[image]

Can anyone help please??

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Now you think you can help? @S.Nick

Comment: Your example doesn't match the image you're showing (the text is completely different and the paper format seems wrong). Besides, what's the point of setting a new text document in the editor while printing?

Comment: You can change text I just put large text to check if it works I tried everything changing the papersize and text but nothing seem to work there is still margin on left side don't know why

Comment: If you can help me then please help me I am stuck with this issue

Comment: I even tried to print the textedit but still the same issue

Comment: This is in the range of my assumption, but how about you use `setPageSize(QPageSize.AnsiA)` AnsiA is the same size of Letter. Even if you print out your document as Letter print size, because the original page size of document is different, I assume that the result may not be as you thought.

Comment: I used excel2image to convert excel to image and then print it it was perfect but in this way I need to have MS Excel installed and it will use win32api to open excel and convert it to image. Do you have any way to convert into image without any need of excel to install in system